# load() isn't working within PHP echo

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following snippet on my index page so that all links clicked on within the navbar will load within the 'content' div:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("a.link").click(function() { 
    return false;
});
  $("#navbar a").click(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content").load(a_href);
  });
});
```

This snippet works fine... But upon loading the page, I check with PHP to see if the index page has an argument to direct it to a specific page, which doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists('page',$_GET)){
    echo "<script>$('#content').load('" . $_GET['page'] . "', 'content')</script>";

} else {
    echo "<script>$('#content').load('home.php')</script>";
}
?>
```

It may be a simple case of "it's staring you in the face but you've been looking at it for too long", but I can't seem to get the PHP snippet to work.

**EDIT:** I wrapped it in document.ready(), and it doesn't seem to have had an effect:

```
    echo "
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#content').load('home.php');
    });
</script>";
```

Comment: both code in the PHP conditions should be in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Also is there any error in your browser's developer console?

Comment: Also in your first condition, `'content'` isnt a valid filter selector it would need to be `'#content'` or `'.content'`.

Comment: Oops, the `'content'` bit was left over from something else I tried. It's the else bit that I'm focusing on right now. I tried wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`, but it seems to have had no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
echo "<script>"
     echo "$(document).ready(function () {";    
if(array_key_exists('page',$_GET)){

     echo "$('#content').load('" . $_GET['page'] . "', 'content');";

} else {

    echo "$('#content').load('home.php');";

}
    echo "});";    
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: I just tried to do this, and it didn't work; upon further inspection, it looks like I didn't have the ending semicolon at the end of the load() call, which is probably why it didn't work, even though my editor wasn't throwing out any syntax errors! Works beautifully, thanks!

Comment: semicolons are not required in javascript. what is the error in your browsers console?

Comment: So it works now? with the `;` semicolon in the end of `$('#content').load('home.php')` this line?

Comment: Very odd... I replaced the snippet with mine that I added in the edit in the original post, and it works. Not quite sure what's going on there, but either way, it's working now.

Comment: May be you're right, It doesn't required `$(document).ready()`, I think the `load` works in the live environment, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well always try Javascript, jquery and css works with Incognito. you're may be a victim of browser cache. :)